# Is there a way to have Google Places Autocomplete country bias without passing region option to script tag?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I don't want a restriction by country like `componentRestrictions` does, rather I want to have a bias so that top results are returned for a given country (by providing country code for example).

The only way to do it so far that I found is to prepend `region` option when loading google maps api like so `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=foobar&v=3.exp&libraries=places,geometry&region=PT`

Is there any way to dynamically pass this region with each call or maybe pass it at a later time from client?

The call I am making is this by the way:

```
const input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['establishment']});

this.autocompleteListener = google.maps.event.addListener(
  this.autocomplete,
  'place_changed',
  () => {
    if (this.autocomplete) {
      const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry && onPlaceChanged) onPlaceChanged(place);
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the country's bounds?

Comment: @geocodezip I only know ISO country code. So I will have to have a bounds for each country somehow, or make another API call to get country bounds before making google places autocomplete call. I was hoping there's easier way similar to how it works if I pass region when loading a script.

Comment: Basically It's hard to have bounds for every possible country in the world, unless I can get json with all the bounds somewhere

Comment: There are only ~200 countries.  You can use Google's geocoder to get one possible bounds for each of them dynamically (at the cost of an extra query).

Comment: I will try this and report back

https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540